# Is missing cockpit-docker no longer in the 20.04 repository?

Tags: apt, docker, 20.04, official-repositories, cockpit

I installed Ubuntu server 20.04 into a vm, to see how if I want upgrade my 18.04. I use cockpit for ease of use on my 18.04. Anyways the cockpit-docker deb is missing from the repository. Why is this? Was this an over site or is their some other reason for it not being part of 20.04?

Comment: https://cockpit-project.org/blog/cockpit-215.html It appears Cockpit Project is deprecating `cockpit-docker` in favor of `cockpit-podman`. Given that I'm not seeing `cockpit-podman` in the Focal repos either (or for that matter podman itself) we may well be out of luck permanently.

Answer (score 6):

Though they do not build `cockpit-docker` for Ubuntu 20.04 or later anymore, you can still install older versions according to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cockpit/+bug/1875028).

I downloaded [cockpit-docker_215-1~ubuntu19.10.1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cockpit/215-1~ubuntu19.10.1/+build/18889196/+files/cockpit-docker_215-1~ubuntu19.10.1_all.deb) and installed manually.
It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to make a difference; I forked the thing and pulled it apart as a plugin.
You can find it on [Github](https://github.com/Xantios/cockpit-docker)

Answer (score 3):

`cockpit-docker` is replaced by `cockpit-podman`

If `sudo apt install cockpit-podman` fails then [[ Upvote the Official Bug ]](https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit-podman/issues/481)

Workaround:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cockpit/215-1~ubuntu19.10.1/+build/18889196/+files/cockpit-docker_215-1~ubuntu19.10.1_all.deb
sudo gdebi cockpit-docker_215-1\~ubuntu19.10.1_all.deb
rm cockpit-docker_215-1\~ubuntu19.10.1_all.deb
```

Working for me:
[image]