# Manage docker\compose containers using cockpit

Tags: 20.04, docker, cockpit

I recently installed Cockpit to manage my 20.04 server and I was trying to setup docker\compose support on cockpit to manage containers.

The only support I see is for podman, Anyone knows how to set up cockpit to monitor and manage docker containers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is missing cockpit-docker no longer in the 20.04 repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230689/is-missing-cockpit-docker-no-longer-in-the-20-04-repository) I hope one of these solutions will fit your needs.

Comment: Hi, @ArturMeinild thanks for the tip,
The solution didn't work for me but that is ok, I will just move to podman instead of docker. I guess it's about time.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Cockpit uses Podman to manage containers and this can be installed using `sudo apt install cockpit-podman podman`. The main user visible difference is that `podman run some_container` replaces the standard `docker run some_container` syntax, though there are a lot of changes under the hood. If you prefer to use Docker instead while maintaining management via Cockpit, there is a [Github repo here](https://github.com/Xantios/cockpit-docker) that might come in handy.